# JS Laravel persistencia de datos

Tags: laravel

El JS realiza su función como corresponde la cual es la de filtrar en los select pero al momento de guardar el formulario y se encuentra un error, se borra los datos traídos por el js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#busines").change(function(){
        var busines = $(this).val();
        //AJAX
        $.get('/getareasfile/'+busines, function(data) {
            var options = "<option value=''>Seleccione una opción...</option>";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                options += '<option value="'+data[i].costcentre_id+'">'+data[i].costcentredesc+'</option>';
            }
        $("#costcentre").removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
        $("#costcentre").html(options);
        });
    });
    $("#costcentre").change(function() {
        var busines = $("#busines").val();
        var costcentre = $("#costcentre").val();
        $.get('/getleadership/'+busines+'/'+costcentre, function(data){
        var leadership = data.name+' '+data.lastname;
            $("#leadershipss").val(leadership);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ¿se borran cuáles datos? ¿dónde?

Comment: en los select al momento de guardar el formulario y no relleno algunos de los campos requeridos al momento en que sale el mensaje los select se ponen en el valor por defecto que es seleccione una opción en vez de quedar con los datos que ya se habían puesto

Comment: Probablemente sea porque la traída de esos datos, solo se hace cuando se ejecuta el evento change de los selects, y no cuando carga la pagina. Mira este codigo de ejemplo https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gv2yeu